# Ternary function in axiomatization of category theory

Tags: category-theory, first-order-logic

I am interested in axiomatizing category theory (for example, the category of categories or category of sets just like Lawvere did). I went  through some sources and everywhere I looked I saw that the composition was axiomatized instead of $\circ(u,v)$ which would be binary function but using ternary function $\Gamma(u,v,w)$ which is interpreted in metamathematics as "$u \circ v = w$". Why is that so? I don't see why we choose this because I feel that $\circ$ is a more natural choice and equality is already assumed while axiomatizing category theory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In traditional first-order logic, functions must be total.  So, if $\circ$ were a binary operation, $\circ(u,v)$ would need to be defined for any two morphisms $u$ and $v$.  This is obviously not desirable, since composition should only be defined when the domain of one morphism matches the codomain of the other.  So, since it is not a total function, you must encode $\circ$ instead as a relation.

See [Model theory: What is the signature of `Category theory`](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1958695/model-theory-what-is-the-signature-of-category-theory) for some related discussion.

Comment: I am not sure I understand why this isn't desirable. Can't I just add as an axiom: $\circ(u,v) = w \implies c(u) = d(v)$, where $c$ is interpreted as codomain and $d$ as domain. Then, even though it is defined for all $u,v$ I can use it only when codomain and domain match.

Comment: Assuming you want the variables in that axiom to be universally quantified, that axiom implies that $c(u)=d(v)$ for all $u$ and $v$.  Indeed, you can substitute the term $\circ(u,v)$ for $w$ to make the antecedent of the implication true no matter what $u$ and $v$ are.

Comment: you are right. Thanks for the help! Can you maybe give some more references about first order axiomatization of categories?